# Does it have to be "to lend the money" when say "someone borrowed me money"?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

For example, someone asked me to borrow my money. But I refused.
Then I talked it with another people, Can I say

> "Yesterday, XX borrowed me money."

Or, I only can say

> "Yesterday, XX asked me to borrow my money."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can only say "Yesterday, XX asked me to borrow my money."

This is close to correct, but not exactly. It should be:

> "Yesterday, XX asked me if he could borrow some money."

or maybe

> "Yesterday, XX asked if he could borrow some money from me."

Don't use me/my twice in this particular sentence. Once is sufficient.

---

> Can I say "Yesterday, XX borrowed me money."

This is not correct for multiple reasons:

1. You refused him. Therefore, he didn't borrow any money, right? So the sentence is false.
2. It should be re-worded:

> "Yesterday, XX borrowed money from me."
>
> "Yesterday, XX borrowed some money from me."

You may say

> "Yesterday, XX borrowed my car."

or

> "Yesterday, XX borrowed my tennis racket."

However "money" is an uncountable noun, and so

> "Yesterday, XX borrowed my money."

almost sounds like he borrowed *all* your money.

If you meant by

> "Yesterday, XX borrowed me money"

this instead:

> "Yesterday, XX borrowed (from) me (some) money"

where the words "from" or "some" are implied, but not spoken.  No, this isn't done, you'd have to include those words, and then re-order them also.